# swagger fromform restrict properties

Tags: .net, swagger-ui, openapi

I have 2 classes offre and domaine, offre is used by a controller.

```
public class Offre
{
    public int? OffreId { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "le tire est obligatoire.")]
    [MaxLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Le titre doit avoir au plus 50 caractères.")]
    [MinLength(10, ErrorMessage = "Le titre doit avoir au moins 10 caractères.")]
   
    public string Titre { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "La description est obligatoire.")]
    [MaxLength(2000, ErrorMessage = "La description doit avoir au plus 2000 caractères.")]
    [MinLength(10, ErrorMessage = "La description doit avoir au moins 10 caractères.")]

    public string Description { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Le salaire est obligatoire")]
    [Range(15, 150, ErrorMessage = "Le salaire doit être compris en tre 15 et 150.")]
    public int Salaire { get; set; } //salaire en k€

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "L'adresse1 est obligatoire.")]
    [MinLength(4, ErrorMessage = "L'adresse1 doit avoir au moins 4 caractères.")]
    [MaxLength(40, ErrorMessage = "L'adresse1 doit avoir au plus 40 caractères.")]
    public string Adresse1 { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string? Adresse2 { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Le code postal est obligatoire.")]
    [MinLength(5, ErrorMessage = "Le code postal doit contenir 5 caractères.")]
    [MaxLength(40, ErrorMessage = "Le code postal doit contenir 5 caractères.")]
    public string CodePostal { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "La ville est obligatoire.")]
    [MinLength(5, ErrorMessage = "La ville doit avoir au moins 5 caractères")]
    public string Ville { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    [NotMapped]
    public IFormFile Image { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "La photo est obligatoire.")]
    public string? URLImage { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    public ICollection<Candidature>? Candidatures { get; set; }
 
    public int DomaineID { get; set; }
 
    public Domaine Domaine { get; set; }
}

public class Domaine
    {
        public int? DomaineId { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage ="le domaine est obligatoire.")]
        [MaxLength(30,ErrorMessage = "Le Titre doit avoir au plus 30 caractères.")]
        [MinLength(3,ErrorMessage = "Le Titre doit avoir au moins 10 caractères.")]
        public string Titre { get; set; } = string.Empty;

        [NotMapped]

        public IFormFile Image { get; set; }

        public string? URLImage { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    }
```

And a controller define like this

```
[HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Offre>> PostOffre([FromForm] Offre offre)
.....
```

When i run swagger on this controller i have
[image: view in swagger]

I don't want the part marked in red because I don't need to re-enter a domain. I try to use jsonignore, but it doesn't work on formulaire. I try to filter properties via swagger api, in this case the properties disappear but it is impossible to validate the form probably because of the constraints on the "domaine.Title" field.

Do you have an idea to solve this because the domain is mandatory for an offer?

Thank you all